# AdMob Ad in UIView() Swift

Tags: swift, admob, uicollectionviewcell, swift5

Can I add a native AdMob ad in a UIView() that is a property of a UICollectionViewCell?

```
let adView: UIView = {
    let ad = UIView()

   (in here I want to show the ad.)

    return ad
}()
```

then in override init I want to add the UIView containing the ad as a subView

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
   addSubview(adView)
}
```

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

This is where you create the view
And another state is responsible for displaying ads, you need to create it first and only then display it with the settings you need

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).